# Which tag of Ruby Docker image should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

As helpful as this is

https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/

I'm looking for a clear cut answer and thought process in deciding which tag of the ruby Docker image I should use for my application (e.g. slim, alpine, onbuildm etc).

Regards,

Comment: If you want to build a Rails 5 app, maybe `rubinius/docker` which is the official Rubinius docker image. Rails 5 uses `puma` as its default server that prefers a Ruby implementation without GIL.

Comment: Is rails built and tested against rubinius?

Comment: Just to clarify I was talking about the difference between ruby:slim, :alpine, etc.